# Get domain name of exchange server

Tags: dns, exchangewebservices

How to get Exchange server 2013 ,  2016 and office 365 domain name using ews api?

If i use AutodiscoverService.GetDomainSettings("domainname") requires domain name need to given as an input.

Is there is a way to get domain name of office 365 server using ews api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no function to get domain name using EWS directly. It needs requires domain name as you mentioned. However, if possible, you can try to the Microsoft Graph API to get your needs. Using the following API of Graph.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains
```

Then it will return:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 192

{
  "authenticationType": "authenticationType-value",
  "availabilityStatus": "availabilityStatus-value",
  "id": "contoso.com",
  "isAdminManaged": true,
  "isDefault": true,
  "isInitial": true,
  "isRoot": true
}
```

And you will see the ID.

Please refer to the link: [Get domain](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/domain_get)

Please see the following test result of mine:
[image]

Comment: I think this also needs domain name .

Comment: Not need. You can use the url: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer to test it. I will post a screenshot for this.